# Property of indicator functions and infinite unions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $(A_j)_{j \in J}$ be a collection of pairwise disjoint sets. Is it then true for the indicator function that
$$ 1_{\bigcup_{j \in J} A_j} = \sum_{j \in J} 1_{A_j}  ?$$
The property holds at least when $J$ is finite, but what about if $J$ is infinite (countably or non-countably)?

Comment: It is almost never appropriate to use both the elementary-set-theory and the set-theory tags on the same question. Please read their descriptions next time and choose only the appropriate one.

Comment: What steps have you taken to solve this problem? This looks straightforward to solve.

Comment: You need to interpret the sum appropriately (as it could have arbitrarily many "summands"). But since at most one term is nonzero, the expression will always make sense.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to sum over more than countably infinitely many indices, i.e.
$$f(x) := \sum\limits_{i\in I} f_i(x)$$
for an arbitrary set $I$ and functions $(f_i)_{i\in I}$, as long as the sum on the right can  be interpreted in the way that **for any fixed $x$, at most countably infinitely many terms $f_i(x)$ are non-zero.**

If all sets are disjoint, this property is of course fullfilled. This is very similar to a [partition of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity).